# grails 2.4.2 ehcache plugin 1.0.5 evicts keys prematurely

Tags: caching, grails, ehcache

Using grails 2.4.2, cache:1.1.8 and cache-ehcache:1.0.5, I find the cache only holds a single entry. As soon as a second entry is added, the first one disappears.

**Configuration**

BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile ":cache:1.1.8"
compile ":cache-ehcache:1.0.5"
```

Config.groovy:

```
grails.hibernate.cache.queries = true

grails {
  cache {
    order = 2000
    enabled = true
    clearAtStartup = true
    shared = true
    ehcache {
      reloadable = false
    }
  }
}

grails.cache.clearAtStartup = true

grails.cache.config = {
  cache {
    name 'siteSettings'
  }
  provider {
    updateCheck false
    monitoring 'on'
    dynamicConfig false
  }
  defaultCache {
    maxElementsInMemory 10000
    timeToIdleSeconds 600
    timeToLiveSeconds 600
    overflowToDisk false
    diskPersistent false
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy 'LRU'
  }
  defaults {
    maxElementsInMemory 10000
    timeToIdleSeconds 600
    timeToLiveSeconds 600
    overflowToDisk false
    diskPersistent false
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy 'LRU'
  }
}
```

cached method in SettingsService.groovy:

```
@Cacheable(value='siteSettings')
public JSONElement getSiteSettings(Integer site){
  log.info "NOT CACHED for this request (${site})"
```

**Logging Output**

1)  first request where site=229 (nothing cached):

```
    Initialised cache: siteSettings
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'siteSettings'.
    siteSettings size: 0
    cacheKeys: 0
    NOT CACHED for this request (229)
    put at siteSettings: [ key = grails.plugin.cache.CustomCacheKeyGenerator$CacheKey@490f0efa, value={"test":229}, version=1, hitCount=3, CreationTime = 1489534645017, LastAccessTime = 1489534976819 ]
```

2)  second request where site=229 (cache holds 229):

```
    siteSettings size: 1
    cacheKeys: 1
    key 229: [test:229]
```

3)  first request where site=282 (cache holds 229):

```
    siteSettings size: 1
    cacheKeys: 1
    key 229: [test:229]
    NOT CACHED for this request (282)
    evicted from siteSettings: [ key = grails.plugin.cache.CustomCacheKeyGenerator$CacheKey@490f0efa, value={"test":229}, version=1, hitCount=3, CreationTime = 1489534645017, LastAccessTime = 1489534976819 ]
    put at siteSettings: [ key = grails.plugin.cache.CustomCacheKeyGenerator$CacheKey@492726a5, value={"test":282}, version=1, hitCount=0, CreationTime = 1489534976848, LastAccessTime = 1489534976848 ]
```

4)  second request where site=282 (cache holds 282, not 229):

```
    siteSettings size: 1
    cacheKeys: 1
    key 282: [test:282]
```

5)  third request where site=229 (cache holds 282, not 229):

```
    siteSettings size: 1
    cacheKeys: 1
    key 282: [test:282]
    NOT CACHED for this request (229)
    evicted from siteSettings: [ key = grails.plugin.cache.CustomCacheKeyGenerator$CacheKey@492726a5, value={"test":282}, version=1, hitCount=3, CreationTime = 1489534976848, LastAccessTime = 1489535172110 ]
    put at siteSettings: [ key = grails.plugin.cache.CustomCacheKeyGenerator$CacheKey@490f0efa, value={"test":229}, version=1, hitCount=0, CreationTime = 1489535172193, LastAccessTime = 1489535172193 ]
```

**Analysis**

1. on the first request where site=229, nothing has been cached. AS EXPECTED
2. on the second request where site=229, the entry keyed on 229 is cached. AS EXPECTED
3. on the first request where site=282, the entry keyed on 229 is cached, but the entry keyed on 282 is not cached. AS EXPECTED
4. on the second request where site=282, the entry keyed on 282 is cached, but the entry keyed on 229 is no longer cached. UNEXPECTED - expected both keys to be cached.
5. on the third request where site=229, the entry keyed on 282 is still cached, but the entry keyed on 229 is not cached. UNEXPECTED - expected both keys to be cached (subsequently, 282 is evicted, while 229 is put, which matches the observed behavior)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where do you source the siteSettings, cacheKeys and key <value>... logging statement? Can you add a cache event listener on Ehcache and see if you effectively get evictions?

Comment: I implemented a CacheEventListener and added the output to my original post. It appears to verify what I suspected: each time an entry is added to the cache, the previous entry is evicted.

Comment: To answer the first part of your question, Louis, the logging statements are sourced in the grails controller action that invokes the cacheable grails service method.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, the configuration was at fault. In order for grails.plugin.cache.ConfigLoader to recognize that your grails.cache declaration in Config.groovy is a Closure, there must be an equals sign (=), like this:

Config.groovy:

```
// wrong
grails {
  cache {
    order = 2000
    enabled = true
    clearAtStartup = true
    shared = true
    ehcache {
      reloadable = false
    }
  }
}

// right
grails {
  cache = {
    order = 2000
    enabled = true
    clearAtStartup = true
    shared = true
    ehcache {
      reloadable = false
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not reflected in the documentation at http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-cache-ehcache/guide/usage.html, which shows an example of this config element without the equals sign.

I discovered this after setting the grails.plugin.cache log-level to 'debug', when this logging output appeared:

```
DEBUG ehcache.EhcacheConfigLoader  - Not including configs from Config.groovy
```

Examining the source code for EhcacheConfigLoader showed that this error message results when the cache.config setting is not a Closure. Adding the equals sign to the config makes it a closure, and the cache configuration from Config.groovy is now loaded, which seems to fix the problem.

Comment: unfortunately, the added equals sign causes grails unit tests to break with this error: `Fatal error running tests: No signature of method: grails.plugin.cache.ehcache.EhcacheConfigLoader.processConfig() is applicable for argument types: (Config$_run_closure2_closure10, null) values: [Config$_run_closure2_closure10@283eea2a, null]`. Unit-tests work ok when equals sign is removed.

Comment: Fixed by disabling all cache-related config for 'test' environment in Config.groovy: `if (!Environment.current.equals(Environment.TEST)) {...`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say, but this whole thread turns out to be based on a mistake. The underlying problem was fixed by removing a line from a grails external config .properties file that appears to have masked the correct definition of grails.cache.config in Config.groovy. The external config was:

```
grails.cache.config.defaultCache.diskStore='java.io.tmpdir'
```

The suggested fix of adding an equals-sign to the grails.cache declaration is incorrect.